# MySQL LAG/LEAD issue

Tags: mysql, mariadb, window-functions

I am trying to move some code from my current host to GoDaddy and am having issues with LEAD/LAG.

I have the following SQL statement in my code:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  LAG(Clients.id,1) OVER w AS 'lag', 
  LEAD(Clients.id,1) OVER w AS 'lead' 
FROM Clients 
WHERE custno IS NOT NULL 
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY Clients.id)
```

On my current host, works perfectly.  They are running 10.3.29-MariaDB.

GoDaddy is running 5.6.49-cll-lve MySQL.  I get the following batch of errors when trying to run the exact same query:

```
20 errors were found during analysis.

An alias was previously found. (near "w" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "w" at position 34)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "AS" at position 36)
Unexpected token. (near "'lag'" at position 39)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 44)
Unexpected token. (near "LEAD" at position 46)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 50)
Unexpected token. (near "Clients" at position 51)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position 58)
Unexpected token. (near "id" at position 59)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 61)
Unexpected token. (near "1" at position 62)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 63)
Unexpected token. (near "OVER" at position 65)
Unexpected token. (near "w" at position 70)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "AS" at position 72)
Unexpected token. (near "'lead'" at position 75)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "AS" at position 129)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 132)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 152)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running this code in a version of MySql that does not support window functions (you need MySql 8.0+).

Instead you could use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  c.id,
  (SELECT MAX(cc.id) FROM Clients cc WHERE cc.id < c.id) AS `lag`,
  (SELECT MIN(cc.id) FROM Clients cc WHERE cc.id > c.id) AS `lead`  
FROM Clients c 
WHERE c.custno IS NOT NULL
```